# how to sum all imp where bid are same..?

Tags: php

here i want to sum all [imp] where [bid] are same..using php and store that value in variable  like $cpc="sum of all cpc" and $cpm="sum of all cpm"...can any one guide how to do this i am new here

```
$data=
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [bid] => CPC
                [imp] => 5566
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [bid] => CPC
                [imp] => 9
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [bid] => CPM
                [imp] => 442664
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [bid] => CPM
                [imp] => 202321
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [bid] => CPM
                [imp] => 16009
            )


    )
```

Comment: Sounds fine. What have you tried so far, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make associative `array` with the result

but every time you will need to check if this `bid` exists or no
in case it exists you will `add` otherwise set it's value to `0`

```
$res = [];
foreach($data as $row){
    if(!isset($res[$row['bid']]))
        $res[$row['bid']] = 0;
    $res[$row['bid']] += $row['imp'];
}

print_r($res);
```

the result would be like this

```
Array ( [CPM] => 15 [CPC] => 45 )
```

Comment: Now how i get key name and its value..?

Comment: you can simplly do that `foreach($res as $key => $value){ echo $key . " " . $value;}`